# Two RK4 method in one program

Tags: fortran, runge-kutta, integration, differential-equations

I want to solve this integral using RK4 by coding in Fortran:

$$R=∫1/a(t)  dt    →         dR/dt=1/a(t) =f(t)$$

Initial point: t=0 (or a=0.001) and R=0

And I have to get a(t) by solving another differential equation:
$$da/dt=1/a+1/a^2 =g(a)$$

Initial point: t=0 and a=0.001

I wrote this code to get a(t):

```
    PROGRAM RK4
      implicit none
      real h,t
      integer n
      read*,h,n
      call Scale_Factor(h,n,t,a)
    END PROGRAM

    !---------------------------------------------

    SUBROUTINE Scale_Factor(h,n,t,a)
      implicit none
      real t,a,k1,k2,k3,k4,h,g
      integer i,n

      t=0
      a=0.001


    Do i=1,n

       k1=h*g(a)

       k2=h*g(a+k1/2.0)

       k3=h*g(a+k2/2.0)

       k4=h*g(a+k3)

       t=t+h

       a=a+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*(1/6.0)

       write(*,*)t,a

    END DO
    END SUBROUTINE

    !-------------------------
    FUNCTION g(a)
      implicit none
      real a,g
      g=sqrt((1.0/a)+(1.0/a**2)) 
    END FUNCTION
```

And I have another similar program for solving the first integral. But I need to use a(t) that this program produces to solve the integral and I do not know how to combine them in a single program.

What I wrote to combine them is this:

```
    Program RK4
    implicit none

    real k1,k2,k3,k4,h,t,R
    integer i,n
    real a
    read*,n,h 


    t=0
    R=0

    Do i=1,n

      k1=h*(1/a(t))

      k2=h*(1/a(t+h/2.0))

      k3=h*(1/a(t+h/2.0))

      k4=h*(1/a(t+h))

      t=t+h

      R=R+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*(1/6.0)

      write(*,*)t,R

    End Do

    end program

    !-----------------------------------------

    SUBROUTINE Scale_Factor(h,n,t,a)
      implicit none
      real t,a,k1,k2,k3,k4,h,g
      integer i,n

      t=0
      a=0.001


    Do i=1,n

       k1=h*g(a)

       k2=h*g(a+k1/2.0)

       k3=h*g(a+k2/2.0)

       k4=h*g(a+k3)

       t=t+h

       a=a+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*(1/6.0)

       write(*,*)t,a

    END DO
    END SUBROUTINE

    !-------------------------
    FUNCTION g(a)
      implicit none
      real a,g
      g=sqrt((1.0/a)+(1.0/a**2)) 
    END FUNCTION
```

But I know it is not correct.

Comment: What specifically is your problem? It looks like you have a simple system of two differential equations that happen to be coupled. That's totally normal. Books on ODE solvers will tell you how to deal with that.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth I edited my question to make my problem clear.

Comment: I still don't understand. You have a system of two ODEs. Why do you want to solve them separately, one after the other, when you could solve them together?

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth Yes you are right but I need a separate code for a. That's why I need to write it in this way.

Comment: Then of course you will need to store $a$ at every time where you evaluate it as the right hand side of the ODE for $R$. You will need to put it into an array rather than just a single scalar variable. That's the price you pay: If you want to solve these two ODEs separately, you'll have to store the entire history of $a$ for when you need it for the equation for $R$.

Answer (score 1):

First one should verify the numerical solution for $a(t)$ against the analytic solution.

$
d_t a = 1/a + 1/a^2 = \frac{a+1}{a^2}
$

Use $b=a+1$, then the ODE becomes

$
\frac{(b-1)^2}{b} db = dt, 
$

from which we find the solution

$
b^2/2 - 2 b - \ln(b) = t
$

This relation (defined up to a constant to satisfy the initial conditions) is not invertible but it is sufficient for verifying the numerical solution for $a(t) = b(t)-1$.

Once $a(t)$ is available, it is trivial to solve numerically the other ODE,

$
d_t R = 1/a
$

To verify $R(t)$ one can find it analytically as well,

$
\frac{dR}{dt} = \frac{dR}{da} \frac{da}{dt} = \frac{1}{a}
$

Using $b=a+1$ this can be rewritten as

$
dR = \frac{b-1}{b} db,
$

which leads to the solution (up to an additive constant to satisfy initial conditions)

$
R = b - \ln(b) 
$